# Java (move point in string)

Tags: move

I have a string = "abc";
And also I have a point ".".
How I can move this point "." in that string("abc").
Example :
Input date = "abc".
Output date = "abc", "a.bc", "ab.c", "a.b.c".

Thanks'.

```
public class MovePoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        String str1 = ".";
        String[] ara = new String[str.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ara[i] = str.substring(i, 1) + str1 + str.substring(1, 2);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ara));

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add a problem statement to your question, and also include any code you have already tried.

Comment: Hello Tim Biegeleisen.
public class MovePoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        String str1 = ".";
        String[] ara = new String[str.length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ara[i] = str.substring(i, 1) + str1 + str.substring(1, 2);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ara));

            }
        }

    }
}

Comment: public class MovePoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abcd";
        String str1 = ".";
        String[] ara = new String[str.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ara[i] = str.substring(i, 1) + str1 + str.substring(1, 2);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(ara));

            }
        }
}

Comment: Please add that to your question. You can `edit` your question. And use a code block to display the code. You will see a short tutorial on how to do that on the right hand side if you edit your post :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. This uses `StringBuilder` as well as a plain char array to avoid having another loop over the array to build the last String, but it therefore consumes more memory.

First I print the first desired output, which is just the unmodified input String. Then I create a `StringBuilder` which can hold all chars from the input + one more for the chosen separator to avoid unnecessary array resizing. Then I initialize the `StringBuilder` so that it is in the form of the second desired ouput `[char, sep, char, ...]`. I am using `StringBuilder` here because it is just more convenient as it has the `append()` function that I need here.

Last but not least I also initialize a char array which will hold the values for the last String to avoid having to iterate over the array twice to generate that.

Now I loop over over the `StringBuilder` starting from one (as its already initialize to the first result with separator) to the last character. In this loop I do three things.

1. Print out the current value of `StringBuilder`
2. Swap the separator with the next character in the `StringBuilder`
3. Put the character and separator to the correct position in the char array as required for the last string

After the loop the last desired output is computed and I just have to print it to the console.

Runtime for this in BigO-notation would be `O(n)`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcd";
    char sep = '.';
    movePoint(str, sep);
}

public static void movePoint(String str, char sep){
    // print first desired output
    System.out.println(str);
    // String builder that can hold str.length + 1 characters, so no unnecessary resizing happens
    var sb = new StringBuilder(str.length() + 1); 
    // fill with first char
    sb.append(str.charAt(0));
    // add separator
    sb.append(sep);
    // add rest of the string
    sb.append(str.substring(1));
    // Array that holds the last string
    var lastStr = new char[str.length() + str.length() - 1];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < sb.capacity() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(sb);
        // build current string
        // swap separator with next character
        var temp = sb.charAt(i);
        sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(i+1));
        sb.setCharAt(i+1, temp);
        // manipulate char array so last string is built correctly
        int doubled = i << 1;
        // set character at correct position
        lastStr[doubled - 2] = sb.charAt(i-1);
        // set separator at correct position
        lastStr[doubled - 1] = sep;
    }
    // add last character of string to this char array
    lastStr[lastStr.length - 1] = sb.charAt(sb.length() - 2);
    // print last desired output
    System.out.println(lastStr);
}
```

Expected output:

```
abcd
a.bcd
ab.cd
abc.d
a.b.c.d
```